# Moderator advanced review stats overflows bounds of page

Tags: feature-request, bug, moderator-tools

The main table on the 'advanced review stats' page isn't sized properly and overflows beyond the bounds of the page, making it extremely hard to read and follow:

[image]

Can this be fixed please? It would also be nice if it could be filtered by username as the table is still quite wide..

Comment: Adding [feature-request], since this will most likely require some design work and thought beyond a single developer on bug duty YOLOing a fix out. (p.s. thanks for the write-up!)

Comment: stats overflow, um....

Comment: @AdamLear any chance this could possibly get some more review?  I'm trying to pull some data out of this for some, ahem, review we need to do but it is quite hard to process as it is.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Honestly... it might be easier for someone (might even be me :)) to just run queries for whatever you need in the short term. Drop me an email (adam@) with a description of what you need out of that table, and I'll see what I can do either to make the data more accessible to you on the site or in terms of running a one-time set of queries to get said data.